# How to pass an object from a mvc controller action to a view using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Can someone help me out I'm new to jQuery, I would like to know how can I pass an object through from a controller action MVC

```
public ActionResult UserGroupSetting()
{
    UserGroupSetting setting = //some code to retrieve the settings
    ViewData["Theme"] = setting.Theme;
    ViewData["Image"] = setting.LogoImage;
    returnView(setting);
}
```

What I want its to get the Theme and the logo image, in a jQuery function, that I will use to update a class in a stylesheet, The theme object contains a colour in Hex form only for now.

If someone can please help me with the call to a jquery function and how will I expose both the image and the theme objects in jquery.. Thanks

Comment: sorry for the being in line with my question, couldnt get it to be structured properly here.

Comment: You can't pass server objects directly to a javascript function. What you could do however, is make an Ajax call from the loaded page to the server that would return the objects

Answer (score 3):

You can return the data in jSon format and let jquery make a call to your action method with `getJSON` method

```
public ActionResult UserGroupSetting()
{
   var result=new { Theme="YourTheme", Logo="YourLogoURL"};
   return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In your page,Call this from your javascript

```
$(function(){
   $.getJSON('YourController/UserGroupSetting', function(data) {
      alert(data.Theme);
      alert(data.Logo);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Shyju, will try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks again shyju it works perfectly, I tried this for only the theme coz it was giving an error abt the size of the logo image, i will sort that one out, but thanks again ;).

Answer (score 1):

if i were you , i would do this:

you can use ViewBag: in action: ViewBag.Setting = setting;

```
  UserGroupSetting setting = //some code to retrieve the settings
  ViewBag.Theme  = setting.Theme;
  ViewData.Image = setting.LogoImage;
  returnView(setting);
```

then in Razor:

```
 @{
    var setting = (UserGroupSetting)ViewBag.Setting;
  }
```

output it to  javascript  tag:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var setting = new setting{
                 Theme = @setting.Theme,
               Image = @setting.Image
        }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution, but one option I've used in the past is to create a hidden `input` in your view and access the value of the `input` in your jQuery code. This would be an example of the code you would have in your view:

```
<input id="someID" type="hidden" value="@TempData["Theme"]" />
```